# How to deduce existence of photons by applying quantum mechanics to Maxwell's equations

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetic-radiation, photons, quantum-electrodynamics, maxwell-equations

Watching this video lecture of Peter Higgs https://youtu.be/QtudlGHoBQ8?t=372, he says (roughly) at one point that Paul Dirac applied quantum mechanics to Maxwell's field equations and deduced the existence of photons (previously predicted by Einstein in the photoelectric effect?).

> **Question.** Mathematically, how does one obtain the existence of photons (or photon-like particles) by applying quantum mechanics to Maxwell's equations of electromagnetism?

**Disclaimer.** I'm a mathematician by training, with pedestrian knowledge in Physics.

Comment: Not completely sure, but maybe what he meant is rather that if you postulate that quantum mechanics applies to electromagnetism, this would automatically imply the quantization of the electromagnetic field into quanta (particles) that you can call 'photons'. Since the Maxwell equations are our best description of classical electromagetism, quantizing them would give information on the properties of these photons.

Comment: @Wouter Thanks for the input. So basically this is an axiomatic statement, and not a theorem (*if QM applies to EM, then photons exist!*) ? Thanks.

Comment: Passing from a classical to a quantum theory is called _quantization_. The [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantization_of_the_electromagnetic_field) could be a starting point for your inquiry.

Comment: This is probably referring to Dirac's 1927 paper [The Quantum Theory of the Emission and Absorption of Radiation](https://royalsocietypublishing.org/doi/10.1098/rspa.1927.0039), which is generally viewed as the inception of quantum field theory. However Higgs is misrepresenting the situation slightly. While the paper does show the existence of photons it does not do it by quantising Maxwell's equations.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here's a stab at a short and intuitive answer (i.e. math lite). Warning, I ignore basically all factors that aren't equal to 1 so sorry if I get something wrong. $\hbar = \pi = 1/2 = 2 = 4 = 1...$ etc.

Solutions to Maxwell's equations can be decomposed into monochromatic electromagnetic waves*. An electromagnetic wave has an (complex) amplitude $a\propto E$ which oscillates in time.
It can be shown that the energy (or energy flux depending on the exact physical situation) in the electromagnetic wave is proportional to the squared amplitude of the wave:

$$
H = \omega a^*a
$$

Instead of expressing the amplitude as a single complex number we can express it in terms of the real an imaginary parts of that number:

$$
a = \text{Re}(a) + i \text{Im}(a) = x + i p
$$

$$
H/\omega = x^2 + p^2
$$

**WERE** this a mass on a spring harmonic oscillator we would identify $x$ and $p$ as the canonically conjugate position and momentum variables for the classical harmonic oscillator. These are known to have a Poission bracket like

$$
\{x, p\} = 1
$$

Canonical quantization works by elevating the canonically conjugate variables to quantum operators (can be thought of as operators on a Hilbert space) with commutation relations:

$$
[\hat{x}, \hat{p}] = i
$$

It then follows that

$$
[\hat{a}, \hat{a}^{\dagger}] = 1
$$

from which one can derive that

$$
H = \omega\hat{a}^{\dagger} \hat{a} = \omega\hat{n}
$$

Where the eigenvalues of $\hat{n}$ are non-negative integers. This is what is meant by the energy of the harmonic oscillator being quantized. Note that this implies that the complex amplitude of the harmonic oscillator is quantized as well.

Back to the electromagnetic field. It turns out** that 1) electromagnetism can be cast in a Lagrangian form, thus giving us a context in which we can discuss canonically conjugate variables and 2) The real and imaginary parts of the electromagnetic field amplitude, $a$, given by $x$ and $p$, can in fact be related to a pair of conjugate variables of electromagnetism. These conjugate variables are related to the electric field and the time derivative of the electric field. There are also relationships, through Maxwell's equations, to the magnetic field.

This means that we are justified in making the theory of electromagnetism quantum by letting $a\rightarrow \hat{a}$ with

$$
[\hat{a},\hat{a}^{\dagger}]=1
$$

This leads us to the conclusion that the energy in a single mode of the electromagnetic is quantized in units of $\omega$, and likewise the amplitude of the electromagnetic wave is also quantized.

This is what a photon is. A photon is a quantized excitation in the electomagnetic wave, in the same way we can have a quantized excitation in the quantum harmonic oscillator. Also, at this point I'll point out that it is possible to have excitations in the *classical* electromagnetic field as well. If you ever find yourself feeling funny about photons try to spend more time thinking about the similarities, rather than the differences, between classical excitations of the electromagnetic field (or any oscillator) and quantum excitations of the same.

As described in the comments, the photon arises from electromagnetism through an application of **canonical quantization** to the canonically conjugate variables which make up a single-mode monochromatic solution to Maxwell's equations.

*These are often taken to be plane waves, but, depending on the boundary conditions for the EM problem, we can decompose the general solution to Maxwell's equations into many different families of spatial modes. Any such decomposition suffices for the description of a photon. The *shape* of the photon is given by the spatial pattern of the spatial mode that we are quantizing. That is photons can have different shapes, and a photon in one mode can be decomposed as a superposition of photons in other modes. There, I answered about 100 physics stack exchange questions about the shape of a photon in this footnote!

**My favorite references for this are [Quantum and Atom Optics](http://atomoptics.uoregon.edu/%7Edsteck/teaching/quantum-optics/) by Daniel Steck and [UC Berkeley Physics 221A/B Lecture Notes](http://bohr.physics.berkeley.edu/classes/221/2021/221.html) by Robert Littlejohn.

Comment: Thanks for the generous answer which is both intuitive and rigorous, with minimal physics ref.

Comment: When reading Fermis treatment of Lippmann fringes it also gets clearer that there is not more to the Photon than you described (it is not like a material entity traveling through space)

Comment: @Jagerber48 What is the meaning of the notation $\hat{a}^\dagger$ used here ?

Comment: Ah, you'll probably referring to Dirac's ladder operators https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_harmonic_oscillator#Ladder_operator_method

Comment: @dohmatob yes, but you should think of $\hat{a}$ as being simply the quantized version of the complex amplitude $a$ and $\hat{a}^{\dagger}$ as being simply the quantized version of the complex conjugate of the complex amplitude $a^*$. Of course we promote $a$ to an operator $\hat{a}$ complex conjugation ($*$) is promoted to the adjoint operation ($\dagger$).

Answer (score 5):

Historically, quantum mechanics was first postulated by Planck as a way to solve the ultraviolet catastrophe that arose when trying to apply thermodynamics to electromagnetism. So, it's not so much that we have quantum mechanics and applied it to E&M, we had E&M and statistical mechanics/thermodynamic and the mismatch between them gave the first hint at QM.

That said, I'll outline a plausible path from Maxwell's equations to being able to deduce in quantum field theory that photons exist as particles.

First, derive the [Hamiltonian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_(quantum_mechanics)) from the [electromagnetic stress-energy tensor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromagnetic_stress%E2%80%93energy_tensor),
$$H = \int \mathrm{d}^3x \left[\frac{\epsilon_0}{2}\mathbf{E}^2 + \frac{1}{2\mu_0} \mathbf{B}^2\right].$$
Second, write the Hamiltonian in terms of the [vector potential](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_vector_potential) and [electric potential](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electric_potential) using $\mathbf{E} = -\nabla \Phi - \partial_t \mathbf{A}$ and $\mathbf{B} = \nabla \times \mathbf{A}$ to get
$$H = \int \mathrm{d}^3x \left[\frac{\epsilon_0}{2}(\nabla \Phi + \partial_t \mathbf{A})^2 + \frac{1}{2\mu_0} (\nabla \times \mathbf{A})^2\right].$$
Third, split the Hamiltonian's terms into contributions from the electric field's solenoidal and divergencful parts using [Helmholtz decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helmholtz_decomposition)
$$H = \int \mathrm{d}^3x \left[\frac{\epsilon_0}{2}(\nabla \Phi + \partial_t \mathbf{A}_D)^2 + \frac{\epsilon_0}{2}(\partial_t \mathbf{A}_S)^2 + \frac{1}{2\mu_0} (\nabla \times \mathbf{A}_S)^2\right].$$
Identify the momentum canonically conjugate to $\mathbf{A}_S$ is $\mathbf{\Pi}_S = \partial_t\mathbf{A}_S$, and $\mathbf{E}_D = -\nabla \Phi - \partial_t \mathbf{A}_D$ to get
$$H = \int \mathrm{d}^3x \left[\frac{\epsilon_0}{2}\mathbf{E}_D^2 + \frac{\epsilon_0}{2}\mathbf{\Pi}_S^2 + \frac{1}{2\mu_0} (\nabla \times \mathbf{A}_S)^2\right].$$
Finally, Fourier transform into mode-space (i.e. Fourier transform the spatial dimensions, not time)
\begin{align}
H &= \int \mathrm{d}^3k \left[\frac{\epsilon_0}{2}\mathbf{E}_D^* \cdot \mathbf{E}_D  + \frac{\epsilon_0}{2}\mathbf{\Pi}_S^* \cdot \mathbf{\Pi}_S + \frac{1}{2\mu_0} |\mathbf{k} \times \mathbf{A}_S|^2\right] \\
&=\int \mathrm{d}^3k \left[\frac{\epsilon_0}{2}\mathbf{E}_D^*\cdot \mathbf{E}_D + \frac{\epsilon_0}{2}\mathbf{\Pi}_S^*\cdot \mathbf{\Pi}_S + \frac{k^2}{2\mu_0} \mathbf{A}_S^*\cdot \mathbf{A}_S\right].
\end{align}
By inspection you can now see that the electromagnetic field consists of two components that are continuum harmonic oscillators (the solenoidal terms) that obey $\omega = k / \sqrt{\mu_0\epsilon_0}$, and one component that is not (the divergenceful term). The harmonic oscillator type terms are what give rise to the states of definite particle number via the [ladder operator formalism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_harmonic_oscillator#Ladder_operator_method), and hence, photons.

The divergenceful (non-photon supporting) term deserves some commentary. In the [Weyl gauge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauge_fixing#Weyl_gauge) it's a kinetic term (because it's the square of a time derivative of a coordinate), in the [Coulomb gauge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauge_fixing#Coulomb_gauge) it's a potential term (the square of a space derivative of a coordinate), and it's mixed in other gauges. Regardless, parameterizing it in terms of the electric field satisfies gauge invariance, and is not a problem quantum mechanically since it has no canonically conjugate counterpart in the Hamiltonian. That means the states of definite $\mathbf{E}_D$ are also eigenstates of the Hamilton.

Of course, this gets more complicated when you start including sources, $\rho$ and $\mathbf{J}$, but only a little so. For more details, I would recommend Chapter 8 of Weinberg's [The Quantum Theory of Fields (Volume 1)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0521550017).

Comment: Thanks for the generous answer with lots of very useful details. Upvoted.

Comment: Answer can be improved by explaning certain steps. For example in the Fourier reformulation of $H$, maybe state that you're using the identity $F_{\nabla \times \textbf v}(\textbf k) = i\textbf{k} \times F_{\textbf{v}}(\textbf{k})$, where $F_{\textbf{v}}(\textbf{k})$ is the Fourier coefficient of the vector field $\textbf{v}$ at frequency $\textbf{k}$.

Comment: @dohmatob As stated, this is an outline, not a proof, because there's more than that going on. In fact, I need to correct something...

Comment: There's nothing quantum about this answer and it does not make it clear how this classical formulation is linked to quantum. It is particularly not helpful to simplify a classical result and say "Ah now all you need to do is the quantum bit, here's a link to a quantum harmonic oscillator."

Comment: @StevenSagona The question was, "How do I deduce quantized excitations?" not, "How do I quantize the electromagnetic field?" 

And how much quantum field theory have you done, yet? Manipulating classical fields before promoting them to operators is standard practice.