# Why does the divergenceful part of the electric field not produce an ultraviolet catastrophe?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetism, thermodynamics, quantum-field-theory

In [this answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/657130/47360) to a question about how to show the electromagnetic field has particle excitations (photons) it shows that the divergenceful part of the electric field doesn't have a field that it is canonically conjugate to to limit its excitations to having definite particle number.

Now, the [ultraviolet catastrophe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ultraviolet_catastrophe) came from trying to figure out the heat energy stored in the electromagnetic field in an empty oven. The [equipartition theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equipartition_theorem) suggests that the energy stored is $kT/2$ per quadratic term in the Hamiltonian.

Here is the final Hamiltonian from the linked answer
$$H=\int \mathrm{d}^3k \left[\frac{\epsilon_0}{2}\mathbf{E}_D^*\cdot \mathbf{E}_D + \frac{\epsilon_0}{2}\mathbf{\Pi}_S^*\cdot \mathbf{\Pi}_S + \frac{k^2}{2\mu_0} \mathbf{A}_S^*\cdot \mathbf{A}_S\right].$$
The solenoidal terms (subscript $S$) get around the ultraviolet catastrphe by the fact that the excitations in the field have quantized particle number, and hence energy.

The first term, though, is not regulated in this fashion. So, what prevents this term from causing an ultraviolet catastrophe?

In an ideal oven where the electric field vanishes on the boundaries, the field will be identically zero within the oven. In a real oven, the walls will have fluctuations in the charge density. Since $\mathbf{E}_D$ is given by
$$\mathbf{E}_D(\mathbf{x}, t) = \frac{1}{4\pi\epsilon_0} \int \mathrm{d}^3 x' \frac{\mathbf{x} - \mathbf{x}'}{|\mathbf{x} - \mathbf{x}'|^3} \rho(\mathbf{x}', t), $$
and thermal fluctuations will ensure transient charge densities exist in the walls of the oven, so the field will definitely store some energy. My own guess is that the charge fluctuations are from quantized excitations in the oven walls (phonons? plasmons?), and that quantization is what prevents a UV catastrophe. I haven't explored this well enough to say sure, though.